# How to override data with placeholder if data == condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, conditional-statements

A user can signup via email and facebook. If he signs up via facebook a random email is generated to get him through the validation process. That email ends with `@mailinator.com`.

Now if a user wants an email reminder for his challenge than how can we replace the default email if that email ends with `mailinator.com` with a placeholder "Enter Email"?

[image]

**challenges controller**

```
class ChallengesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :update_user_email, if: proc {|c| c.current_user.present? && c.params[:email].present? }

  def update_user_email
    email = params[:email]
    current_user.update_attribute(:email, email)
  end
end
```

**challenges form**

```
<%= form_for(@challenge)  do |challenge| %> 
   <%= f.collection_check_boxes :send_email, Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES, :downcase, :to_s %>
    Send email to <%= text_field_tag :email, current_user.email %>
<% end %>
```

**user model**

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  user.email = SecureRandom.hex + "@mailinator.com"
  user.save!
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want something like this.

```
<% if current_user.email.end_with? "@mailinator.com" %>
  <%= email_field_tag :email,  nil, placeholder: 'Enter email...' %>
<% else %>
    Send email to <%= text_field_tag :email, current_user.email %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Not "something like this". Exactly like this. Thank you :]